# how to make a callable implementing class multithread fast with parallel execution?

Tags: java, callable

i am creating a class(**CheckCon.java**) that implements callable interface which basically returns the no. of devices Connected to the network. the problem is that i donot know how to execute it correctly because the results returned are really slow as compared to traditional multithreading. and i need to return values to a class in (**NetScan.java**). Kindly Help me execute it properly.
code for CheckCon.java (callable implementing class):

```
public class CheckCon implements Callable<Object>{
int startindex,endindex;
ArrayList<Object> list;
byte[] ip;

public CheckCon(int startindex, int endindex, byte[] ip) {
    this.startindex = startindex;
    this.endindex = endindex;
    this.ip = ip;
    list = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Override
public ArrayList<Object> call() throws Exception {

    for(int i =startindex;i<endindex;i++){

        try {

                        ip[3] = (byte)i;
                        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByAddress(ip);
                        if (address.isReachable(1000))
                        { 
                           System.out.println("Name is......"+address.getHostName()+"\tIP is......."+address.getHostAddress());

                        }
                        else if (!address.getHostAddress().equals(address.getHostName()))
                        {
                            String host = address.getCanonicalHostName();
                            String ipaddress =address.toString().replace(host+"/", "");
                            Object[] data = {host,ipaddress};
                            list.add(data);
                            System.out.println("Name is......"+address.getHostName()+"\tIP is......."+address.getHostAddress());


                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("nothing");
                            // the host address and host name are equal, meaning the host name could not be resolved
                        }           } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(NetScan.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(NetScan.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
    }


    return list;
    }
}
```

and the class Calling NetScan.java

```
  private void getDataForTable() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
   ExecutorService executor =Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    for(int i =0; i<26 ; i++){

       if(s == 250){
           Future<Object> f =executor.submit(new CheckCon(s,s+5,ip));
           list.add(f);
       break;
       }else{
           Future<Object> f =executor.submit(new CheckCon(s,s+10,ip));
           list.add(f);
           s= s+10;
       } 
    }


   dm = new DefaultTableModel(ColumnName,0){
        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
        return false;
        }
        };
   for(Future<Object> f : list){
       dm.addRow((Object[]) f.get());
   }}
```

I am creating 25 threads checking 10 IP's in each thread.

Comment: reason for downvote??

Comment: Performance in the multithreading application depends on lots of factored like a number of threads, type of job doing by a thread etc. Also, read about how  Future#get() works.

Comment: i agree with you @AmitBera but when creating the executor with fixed threads with 25 threads i want it to execute the for loop in callable and need to get all ip address in 10 seconds but that is not the case it takes 1 second for each step resulting in providing me result in 255 seconds

Comment: Why are you creating thread pool size of 25? Is there any specific reason? How much CPU intensive work you are doing in each thread?

Comment: It's short term process that just wants each thread to execute for 10 seconds in which it accesses the ip address in the network  with 1 second response time

Comment: Looking at my code can you tell me where is the error as you have fully clarified my question

Comment: Try!! Reduce the thread pool size to available CPU core on your system and also use CompletableFuture instead of Future.

Comment: Thank you @AmitBera! i'll look into it

Answer (score 0):

I removed the CheckCon.java and edited the NetScan to get what i Want thanks to @amit-bera . i Created a thread and asked the completablefuture to runasync with executor defining the no.of threads i require.

```
ExecutorService e =Executors.newFixedThreadPool(25);
    for(int i =0;i<255;i++){
        final int j =i;
    f =  CompletableFuture.runAsync(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {


        try {

                        ip[3] = (byte)j;
                        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByAddress(ip);
                        if (address.isReachable(1000))
                        { 
                           System.out.println("Name is......"+address.getHostName()+"\tIP is......."+address.getHostAddress()+j);

                        }
                        else if (!address.getHostAddress().equals(address.getHostName()))
                        {
                            String host = address.getCanonicalHostName();
                            String ipaddress =address.toString().replace(host+"/", "");
                            Object[] data = {host,ipaddress};
                            dm.addRow(data);

                            System.out.println("Name is......"+address.getHostName()+"\tIP is......."+address.getHostAddress()+j);


                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("nothing"+j);
                            // the host address and host name are equal, meaning the host name could not be resolved
                        }           } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(NetScan.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(NetScan.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
    }


    },e);   
        }
```

added this content to a method.

Answer (score 0):

As per my obervationa please used singolton java pettern.example i am giving below.singolton alwaus retun instance so you save request response time on thread.

Thread is light-wight process but still initilised thread at whenever need.please make sure that thread work based on your server configrationa.
if you are using linux system
used **TOP** command to usage of your system perfomance and process execution on threadiwse.

i try and its work fine on my system.

class Singleton
{

```
private static Singleton single_instance = null;
public String s;
private Singleton()
{
    s = "Hello I am a string part of Singleton class";
}
public static Singleton getInstance()
{
    if (single_instance == null)
        single_instance = new Singleton();

    return single_instance;
}
```

}